# Finding the exit code of a shell command in elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I call a command from the shell using `shell-command-to-string`. However, I want not only its output, but also the command's exit code.

How do I get this?

Comment: This looks difficult; about the only command that I can see doing this is `call-process` with some processing applied to a temporary buffer that would be created...  Something like `(setq ret-val (call-process "ls -l" nil "mytempbuf" nil))`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`shell-command-to-string` is just a convenience wrapper around more fundamental process functions.

A good function to use for simple synchronous processes is [`call-process`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Synchronous-Processes.html). Call process will return the exit code from the process and you can redirect all output to a buffer that you can use [`buffer-string`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-Contents.html) on to get the text.

Here's an example:

```
;; this single expression returns a list of two elements, the process 
;; exit code, and the process output
(with-temp-buffer 
  (list (call-process "ls" nil (current-buffer) nil "-h" "-l")
        (buffer-string)))


;; we could wrap it up nicely:
(defun process-exit-code-and-output (program &rest args)
  "Run PROGRAM with ARGS and return the exit code and output in a list."
  (with-temp-buffer 
    (list (apply 'call-process program nil (current-buffer) nil args)
          (buffer-string))))

(process-exit-code-and-output "ls" "-h" "-l" "-a") ;; => (0 "-r-w-r-- 1 ...")
```

Another note: if you end up wanting to do anything more complex with processes, you should read the documentation for `start-process`, and how to use sentinals and filters, it is really a powerful api.

Comment: Mmm... why do you use `apply` in the second version? Just curious.

Comment: the args passed to `call-process` are variadic, that means I can't just pass the args from `process-exit-code-and-output` into `call-process` because it takes many args, not a list of args. `apply` is a neat function because it also uses variadic args, but it a special behavior. If the last argument given to `apply` is a list, the elements are used as if they were given individually. This is done for convenience in cases just like this that use variadic args. For example: (apply '+ 1 2 3 (4 5)) == (apply '+ 1 2 3 4 5)

Comment: Ahh, I see. I didn't remember that call was variadic. Thanks!